# Jquery .css() not working (possibly caused by something else)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to insert some CSS rules with JavaScript and jQuery for a form.
Unfortunately it doesn't work.
On click of whatever input I  want to do some checking on all the inputs with the same "name" and apply or remove classes or CSS rules.
Here's my Html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input1" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="John">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-1">Name:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input2" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="Doe">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-2">Surname:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input3" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="Passions">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-3">Passions:</label>
```

Here's my script with some explanations:

```
    //On Click of all the elements with name="input-class"        
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="input-class"]').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
            
            //Get all Inputs in a Static NodeList
            const inputer = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="input-class"]');
            
            //Convert the List into an Array
            var btnsArri = Array.from(inputer);
            
            
            //Loops through all the array on inputs
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < btnsArri.length; i++) {
                
                if(btnsArri[i] === document.activeElement){
                    
                    if(btnsArri[i].value === ""){
                        console.log(i + ' is empty and selected')
                        //Recreate the name of the class
                        j = 1
                        h = j + i;

                        var label = 'form-label-input-' + h;
                        var inputChanger = $(btnsArri[i]).attr('class').split(' ')[3];

                        console.log(label)
                        
                        //add CSS Rule
                        //------------------------THAT'S WHERE I'M STUCK..--------------------
                       setTimeout(function(){ $(inputChanger).css({"width":"105%"})}, 0);
                        setTimeout(function(){ $(label).css({"font-size":".6rem"})}, 0);
                    }
                    
                    if(btnsArri[i].value !== ""){
                        console.log(i + ' is full and selected')
                    }
                    
                }
                
                if(btnsArri[i] !== document.activeElement){
                    if(btnsArri[i].value === ""){
                        console.log(i + ' is empty')
                    }
                    if(btnsArri[i].value !== ""){
                        console.log(i + ' is full')
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }) 
    })
```

The code is working just fine it's just the part `setTimeout(function(){ $(inputChanger).css({"width":"105%"})}, 0);`
`setTimeout(function(){ $(label).css({"font-size":".6rem"})}, 0);` that doesn't work. Worst it's not returning any error So i'm a bit lost.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Based on your code, it looks like your selectors are incorrect.

Comment: What does console.log(label) return? I believe you are expecting a class selector like this ".my-class" but you are getting "my-class". The same goes for inputChanger.

Comment: Thank you! yes it's corrected and its working like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the selectors are wrong, you seem to be using jquery and are trying to access the items by class name, the code should be like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('.'+inputChanger).css({"width":"105%"})}, 0);
setTimeout(function(){ $('.'+label).css({"font-size":".6rem"})}, 0);
```

It seems that you've decided to use unique class names for this purpose but you could also use your input1, input2, and input3 as unique IDs of your input elements in which case you would then access them through $('#'+theId)

Comment: Oh boy... That's embarrassing... But it is indeed what i was missing!  A big THANKS to you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code:

```
var label = 'form-label-input-' + h;
var inputChanger = $(btnsArri[i]).attr('class').split(' ')[3];
console.log(label)
//add CSS Rule
//------------------------THAT'S WHERE I'M STUCK..--------------------
setTimeout(function(){ $(inputChanger).css({"width":"105%"})}, 0);
setTimeout(function(){ $(label).css({"font-size":".6rem"})}, 0);
```

This will fail due to an improper selector. You set `label` to a String value: `form-label-input-2`. I am assuming this should be a Class name. So the the proper format for a Class Selector will include a `.`, like so:

```
$(".form-label-input-2").css("font-size", ".6rem");
```

I would advise you use the following:

```
var label = '.form-label-input-' + h;
```

I would also advise not using `setTimeout`, there is no benefit.

```
var label = '.form-label-input-' + h;
var inputChanger = $(btnsArri[i]).attr('class').split(' ')[3];
console.log(label);
$(inputChanger).css("width", "105%");
$(label).css("font-size", ".6rem"});
```

You also don't need to use Objects to set one Style Rule. Best to use them for multiple rule changes at once.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your quick thorough answer! i'm a bit embarrassed by my missing that '.'   I'm gonna stop using setTimout as you advise. For the Object, I'm planning to change multiple rules at once :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `.` here. You need to access the items by class name. check below snippet.

```js
//On Click of all the elements with name="input-class"        
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="input-class"]').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', event => {
            
            //Get all Inputs in a Static NodeList
            const inputer = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="input-class"]');
            
            //Convert the List into an Array
            var btnsArri = Array.from(inputer);
            
            
            //Loops through all the array on inputs
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < btnsArri.length; i++) {
                
                if(btnsArri[i] === document.activeElement){
                    
                    if(btnsArri[i].value === ""){
                        console.log(i + ' is empty and selected')
                        //Recreate the name of the class
                        j = 1
                        h = j + i;

                        var label = 'form-label-input-' + h;
                        var inputChanger = $(btnsArri[i]).attr('class').split(' ')[3];

                        console.log(label)
                        
                        //add CSS Rule
                        //------------------------THAT'S WHERE I'M STUCK..--------------------
                       setTimeout(function(){ $('.'+inputChanger).css({"width":"105%"})}, 0);
                        setTimeout(function(){ $('.'+label).css({"font-size":".6rem"})}, 0);
                    }
                    
                    if(btnsArri[i].value !== ""){
                        console.log(i + ' is full and selected')
                    }
                    
                }
                
                if(btnsArri[i] !== document.activeElement){
                    if(btnsArri[i].value === ""){
                        console.log(i + ' is empty')
                    }
                    if(btnsArri[i].value !== ""){
                        console.log(i + ' is full')
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }) 
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input1" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="John">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-1">Name:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input2" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="Doe">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-2">Surname:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input3" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="Passions">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-3">Passions:</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Sometimes i forget the littlest of things:v)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already has a solution. It fixed the problem of OP. But as jQuery was used in this snippet I would like to point out that it could do so much more for you, and that with writing less code:

```js
$('input[name=input-class]').each(function(i){
  $(this).click(function(){
    console.log((i+1)+' entry, '+(this.value.length?'filled.':'empty so far.'));
    $(this).css('width','90%').next().css('font-size','.6em')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input1" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="John">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-1">Name:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input2" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="Doe">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-2">Surname:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-style input3" name="input-class" value="" placeholder="Passions">
<label class="form-label-input form-label-input-3">Passions:</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it! This is very helpful,